# Checkout Location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, check-out

Easy question but has anybody seen the advanced -> checkout option in SharePoint 2013. I want checkout to be shown in the first screen rather than the advanced section if possible.

[image: Checkout Location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that'll count as first screen, but if you click on the document itself it's there on the ribbon.

[image]